# React Navigation doesn't render route if useLazyLoadQuery is called

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, relayjs

I have a very basic `react-navigation` and `relay` setup. The data is loaded and the `console.log` outputs the data, but the `View` and `Text` are not rendered and I only see a blank screen.

```js
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const data = useLazyLoadQuery(QUERY, {});
  console.log('data', data);
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Data: {data.id}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you share more details?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `useLazyLoadQuery` might be putting react into a suspended fallback state that's not being caught. Something like this should get you up and running:

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <Data />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

const Data = () => {
  const data = useLazyLoadQuery(QUERY, {});
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Data: {data.id}</Text>
    </View>)
}
```

Comment: I have <Suspense /> higher up the Component tree, would that suffice, or should there be a <Suspense /> on every component?